How can 802.11be avoid the Shannon-Hartley theorem?
I read that 802.11be is expected to have a max speed of 40,000Mbps, but only a bandwidth of 320MHz.  How is that possible?  My (new) understanding of the Shannon-Hartley theorem says this would require an SNR of about 10^40, which seems ludicrous to me.  See also Can we break the Shannon capacity? .  That one mentions beamforming and MIMO, and elsewhere I see that 802.11be supports 16 "spatial streams" - is that the key?  Basically separating the signals in space so you can use the same frequency multiple times?  I calculate that 40,000Mbps / 16 = 2500Mbps would only each require an SNR of like 100 or so, which seems much more achievable.  Is that the main trick to escaping the Shannon-Hartley theorem, here, or are there other key components?

Probably better to ask on [electronics.se].

The ~40 Gbit marketing claim is for a 'single user scenario' (or single device in a clean environment etc.) only so it is basically meaningless.
As for the pratical improvements of WiF 7, there are many. You can look here for a more comprehensive list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11be
The standouts are:

4K QAM (more data per signal basically)
More channels in use at once (including contiguous and non-contiguous frequency ranges across 5 and 6 ghz)
Improved OFDMA
Increased MIMO limit (doubled to 16)
Preamble puncturing to improve use of crowded frequency ranges
Better traffic scheduling/sharing
More intelligent power management for 6Ghz spectrum

Basically the much wider effective frequency channels and increased MU-MIMO streams increases the theoretical top performance regardless of the Shannon limit by simply doing more transmission at the same time on different frequencies where there is less noise. Essentially just making an ever wider freeway to transport more cars at the same average (or slightly faster) speed compared to the previous design.

It seems like 4K QAM, OFDMA, and preamble puncturing are just more clever ways of using a given chunk of bandwidth, and so according to theory can only get it closer to the SH theoretical optimum, not exceed it.  Can it use multiple disjoint 320 MHz channels at once?  Traffic scheduling and power management sound like maybe you could count that as a (sort of side-channel) method of reducing noise and increasing signal, which I suppose counts, though not nearly enough for the 10^40 SNR calculated above.  If I understand the MIMO limit, that's the 16 "spatial streams" I highlighted as key, yeah?

Yes, when you toss them all together you get the kind of improvement that WiFi7 is proposing but the peak theoretical performance improvement you are looking for (40Gbps) is only under very specific and unrealistic circumstances. Basically in a test chamber with specialized hardware, it might happen. Otherwise, you will probably see some 10-20% improvement in most real world scenarios over WiFi6/WiFi6e. No one is proposing a radical improvement in raw signal rate, just more, wider channels at the same time with a bit of efficiency gain.
